# how can i convert a string in a column to an array and then query a specific position in that arrray?

Tags: postgresql

[image]

So i want to convert this string to an array using string_to_array and then query for the 3rd comma value.

I had something in mind like this

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE string_to_array(data1, ',')[2] = '2'
```

But this does not seem to work. Does anybody have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

To get the third element :

```
SELECT *, elements[3] as third_element
FROM table1
  CROSS JOIN string_to_array(data1, ',') as elements
```

To query on the third element :

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
  CROSS JOIN string_to_array(data1, ',') as elements
where elements[3]::varchar = '2'
```

Note : first element is at position 1 (not 0)

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/vSltHnVV)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not working because the array elements are 1-based in PostgreSQL, not 0-based like in many other programming languages.

Try this code, I changed your query to look for rows where the string_to_array array's third member equals '2':

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE (string_to_array(data1, ','))[3] = '2';
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: As it happens the first three values in the example are `11,2,2` so it would work anyway. The real problem is that without the brackets around the function-call you will get a syntax error. Why the OP decided the syntax error wasn't important to share I don't know.

Comment: Thank you Maimoona my problem was the indexing. Sorry i didnt mention the syntax but in my orginal Query my syntax was unknowlingly correct @Richard

Answer (score -2):

Array indexing in Postgres starts from 1 and not 0, so to get the third element you have to use index 3, try modifying your query;

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE string_to_array(data1, ',')[3] = '2';
```

Comment: Same syntax error the OP had in his example.